# Url passed variable to page and rewrite url

Tags: php, variables, url-rewriting

Is it possible to pass data in a custom link to my php site from an email,

e.g.  http://somedomain.com/page.php?id=1&type=2&item=3

then when it hits my site, it gives the information to the page and rewrites the url, so it's clean

e.g.  http://somedomain.com/page.php

And the page renders based on the information in the original url.

Just to be clear I understand how to get variables from the url.

Comment: use `$_GET['id']` `$_GET['type']` `$_GET['item']` and then `POST` them on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desire implementation by the POST method. Try the below code.

```
<?php
$id = !empty($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:"1";
$type = !empty($_GET['type'])?$_GET['type']:"a";
$item = !empty($_GET['item'])?$_GET['item']:"b";

if(count($_POST) == 0 && !empty($id) && !empty($type) && !empty($item)){
?>
<form method="POST" id="myForm" action="page.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $type; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"/>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
</script>

<?php 
}

if(count($_POST) > 0 && !empty($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['item'])){
    var_dump('post',$_POST,count($_POST));
}
?>
```

Hope this help!!!